# How to find metrics of Kafka running on an Azure VM in Application Insights?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-application-insights, jmx

I have an Azure VM running Kafka. I followed the steps in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent to connect Kafka to Application Insights and it is working. The web page says that there are auto-collected dependencies for Kafka. How does this work and where do I find the metrics in Application Insights?
Or should I add the JMX metrics in the json file? How do I find the correct objectName and attribute if this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

> where do I find the metrics in Application Insights

Below code will help you in enabling the Metrics feature

```cs
metrics = settings.EnableMetrics();
```

And the code will help you in adding advanced data

```cs
var logicalAddress = settings.LogicalAddress();
var discriminator = logicalAddress.EndpointInstance.Discriminator;
var instance = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

var endpoint = settings.EndpointName();
var queue = settings.LocalAddress();

var telemetryConfiguration = settings.Get<TelemetryConfiguration>();

collector = new ProbeCollector(
    telemetryConfiguration,
    endpoint,
    discriminator,
    instance,
    queue
);

metrics.RegisterObservers(collector.RegisterProbes);
```

For further information check [Metrics in Application Insights.](https://docs.particular.net/samples/logging/application-insights/#introduction)

You can even go through [Application Insights Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/kafka/apache-kafka-log-analytics-operations-management) for complete information.

Also find [Getting Started with Metric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/get-metric).